# Using MySQL while my WordPress files are not in the root FTP folder

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ftp

I'm attempting to understand mySQL databases and have created one on my GoDaddy account in ordered to run a WordPress blog through my FTP.

I've already built a site though so I've put all of the WP files into a folder in my FTP (not in the root). It's not finding the database now and I'm assuming it's because the WP info isn't in the root folder. I'm trying not to put it in the root folder for organizational purposes since there are already a bunch of files.

Here's an example of where the install file is for WordPress:

www.mydomain.com/blog/wp-admin/install.php

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WP database was preconfigured and set up after you installed the addon.

You will find your dataase in your **phpMyAdmin portal** found through the "Databases" tab in your GodDaddy hosting account.

You can not access your database through an FTP client.

Comment: Ok, I just took a look at that and was able to access. I guess I'm still a little uneducated on the use of the mySQL database with WordPress. I haven't actually installed WP yet and it seems like I need to be able to access the MySQL through it. Here's the example I watched: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nse3Gdtvs4 . Is it different through GoDaddy?

Comment: After you install the wordpress plugin, go back to the phpmyadmin portal and you will see your dataase there.

Comment: It's not actually letting me install the WordPress plugin though (which is where I'm stuck). I'm not sure if I have the wrong username and database name. My question to the other answerer was that I was wondering if there is a prefix (through GoDaddy) for the username and database name. In that video I added as a link, the guy had a username for his MySQL database but needed a prefix for it through his server when he was editing his wp-config.php . I've tried with a prefix and without a prefix but I'm not entirely sure if the names are correct. Is there a way to double check that?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, I had to get the configuration information from the GoDaddy account page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: no problem. and yea your connection information is in the same databases page that you access the portal from.

Answer (score 0):

The location of your WordPress files aren't important when it comes to locating the database.  Your WP files can be located anywhere that's accessible on the web.  You need to make sure you know the location of the MySQL and have a correct login and password to access this database.

Comment: Do you know if there's a certain prefix to the username and database name when you use GoDaddy? I'm basing some of this off of a video that I watched: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nse3Gdtvs4 where there was a username 'prefix' that had to be used in the wp-config.php file. I don't see that prefix from my GoDaddy account (and I've tried it with and without and it doesn't seem to work). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not acquainted with the particulars of GoDaddy's setup, just WordPress.

Comment: Oh ok, well it's a good start (I'm literally just learning). I voted you up but then it got voted down. It was a good start for me!